# How can I make the underlying file access actions of git log visible

Tags: git, logging, dtruss

I would like to visual the file system actions that are caused by running something like `git lg -n3`. I'm on a Mac. So I thought, ok let's run `dtruss git lg -n3`.

Unfortunately this doesn't give me the expected output. I would expect to see file access to some files at `.git/objects`.

Is `dtruss` not what I'm looking for?

I should add that I also don't see the output of `git log` when I run it through `dtruss`. If I run `dtruss git` I see the output of the git command overview at least. Am I doing it wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok, turns out it's a problem with how dtruss handles the multi word command `git log`.  If I use `dtruss /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-log` it works as expected.

I can go further and run `dtruss /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-log -n3 2>&1 | grep access` and get pretty much what I was looking for. So the only remaining question really would be why I have to use the full path to `git-log` instead of just the `git log` command.

Comment: I have `access(".git/objects/f8/f38eae3f999ad65a8818862da946708bf7f15f\0", 0x0, 0x100276865)             = 0 0`. Seems works as you expect.

Comment: mmh, I don't have those in the output of `dtruss git lg -n3` :-/

Comment: Riiiight... As I see it appears first time, and then doesn't. Looks like that files are cached, so it is not accessed second time.

Comment: Pretty sure you want strace.  That will tell you every system call it makes (check options for following forks).

Comment: @kan I just tried it out on a fresh git repository and even for the first call to `dtruss git lg -n3` I don't see those files getting accessed :-/

Comment: But I also don't see the output of `git log` when I run it through `dtruss` so I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok, turns out it's a problem with how dtruss handles the multi word command `git log`.  If I use `dtruss /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-log` it works as expected.

Comment: I'd guess that dtruss command line parsing is a bit weird and it thinks `log` and `-n3` is meant for it. The sane (GNU) way would be to support `--` separator as in `dtruss -- git log -n3`. I don't have Mac to test, though. Another possible fix would be to run `dtruss "git log -n3"`.

Comment: unfortunately `dtruss "git log -n3` doesn't work. It doesn't seem to perform the `git log` at all then :(

Answer (score 2):

On UNIXoid systems like Linux (embedded or desktop) I like to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) for that purpose, e.g. *inotifywait* or *inotifywatch*, depending on my exact purpose.

**Edit:** I wonder why someone has downvoted my answer. Inotify-tools is a specialised set of tools for monitoring file system access, and this is what was asked. I would appreciate a remark with a request for clarification first, if my answer does not seem to be good or relevant enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to try `strace`. For example, this may be the result you're looking for:

```
strace -q -f -e trace='open,stat' git log -n3
```

or if you really want all file system access

```
strace -q -f -e trace=file git log -n3
```

should do it. Drop the `-f` part if you don't need to trace the stuff done by `less` and other possibly executed forked processes. As usual, `man strace` will be worth reading...

Comment: It seems that `dtruss` already is the `strace` alternative on Mac.

Comment: @Christoph Are you using OS X? You should mention that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Added it now.